# Match results in SQL table where not in same order as joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have two tables, with a large amount of data in. I've taken one row from both tables to provide this example.

I need to match any user records in Table 1, to Table 2 where the specialties match.

I can't use an IN clause, because my results need to match **EXACTLY** what is in Table 1 'specialties' column to 'specialties' in Table 2.

The issue is that in Table 2, the order of the specialties does not match that of the specialties in Table 1.

I would want userID = 1 from Table 1 to match this row in Table 2 because they have the same specialties. Does any one have an idea of how I can get this data to match?

**Table 1**:

```
select
   userID
   ,specialties
from table1
where userID = 1
```

| userID | specialties |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Water & Environment, Built Environment, Flood & Flood risk, Civil & Environmental, Specialists, Environmental |

**Table 2:**

| specialties |
| --- |
| Built Environment, Water & Environment, Civil & Environmental, Environmental, Specialists, Flood & Flood risk |

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: Your data model is flawed, Specialities should be a table with the UserId FK and each *row* would be a single speciality - then your task is much simpler (and more performant)

Comment: It's not my data model, it's a clients sadly. I'm aware of the issues of storing data like that, however they are migrating to ourselves

Answer (score 0):

the function you need to use is below. top(100) is SQL Server limitation there. If You have more than 100 commas in your "strings with a commas" you need to increase this top to 1000 or more.

```
create function sort_str(@in_str as nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max) as
begin
declare @out_str as nvarchar(max)
select @out_str = string_agg(value,',') from
(
select top(100) value from
    (select value from string_split(@in_str,',')) x
order by value
) m
return @out_str
end
```

Example:

```
select dbo.sort_str(cast('1,2,5,4,7,6,3' as nvarchar(max)))
```

Result:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7

When comparing strings from tables do this way:

```
where dbo.sort_str(cast(string_from_table_1 as nvarchar(max)))=dbo.sort_str(cast(string_from_table_2 as nvarchar(max)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not store multiple values in the same column, they should be in a separate table in separate rows. But given your constraint on not modifying that, we can split the values within the query.

**This then becomes a question of *[Relational Division Without Remainder](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)*.**

There are a number of solutions, here are two:

Solution 1:

- Within an `EXISTS`, take the split values and join them to `table2`'s split values...
- ... having first calculated the total number of rows in `table2` using a window function
- Then count the rows, ensuring that the total number of joined rows is the same as the total from `table2` before joining

```sql
SELECT
  t1.userID,
  t1.specialties
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.userID = 1
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(t1.specialties, ',') s1
    JOIN (
        SELECT
          s.value,
          TotalRows = COUNT(*) OVER ()
        FROM table2 t2
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t2.specialties, ',') s
    ) t2 ON TRIM(t2.value) = TRIM(s1.value)
    GROUP BY ()
    HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(t2.TotalRows)
);
```

Solution 2:

- Within an `NOT EXISTS`, take the split values and `FULL JOIN` them to `table2`'s split values. So any non-matches become null
- Then take any rows that have null in either column.
- Any result from this means the outer row is excluded

```sql
SELECT
  t1.userID,
  t1.specialties
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.userID = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(t1.specialties, ',') s1
    FULL JOIN table2 t2
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t2.specialties, ',') s2
      ON TRIM(s2.value) = TRIM(s1.value)
    WHERE s1.value IS NULL OR s2.value IS NULL
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a6652fc4a10a9c4b08ca9c36204a7ee3)